# Define ContextDataProvider in Log4j2 at creation time of Logger

Tags: java, log4j2

I would like to provide a custom ContextDataProvider to Log4J2 Loggers as defined in https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#ContextDataProvider

I know and tried Java SPI to define a `ContextDataProvider` in `META-INF/services/org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.ContextDataProvider` but for some reason the Provider is ignored/never called in my specific work environment (Eclipse with integrated Tomcat and other custom implementations).

Is there any other way to define a `ContextDataProvider`, e.g. in source code when creating a Logger or something similar?

TIA

Comment: I have the same problem: my custom ContextDataProvider is never called

Comment: @kopfarzt: How do you use your provider?